# Unity Facebook SDK & iOS 14.5: login miss understanding

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, ios14.5

Apple updated IDFA terms for iOS 14.5 and as a result, Facebook released the new way to login called “Facebook Limited Login”. The question is: should I change Facebook login mode from `LoginWithReadPermissions()` to “Facebook Limited”? I’ve got some issues using different login modes on different platforms and haven’t found any information about why can’t I continue using `LoginWithReadPermission()`. My app doesn’t collect any data and uses Facebook only to login into Playfab. Have you already got the same issues with iOS 14.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to what permissions you are requesting or what data your app does collect.
According to Facebook, this is how they defined Limited Login:

> Facebook Login offers a Limited Login mode. When you use the limited version of Facebook Login, the fact that a person used Facebook Login with the app will not be used to personalize or measure advertising effectiveness.

So you will have to use this API to login instead of the previous one:

```
FB.Mobile.LoginWithTrackingPreference(LoginTracking.LIMITED, scopes, "nonce123", this.HandleResult);
```

For more information regarding how to use Limited Login, [check out this guide by Facebook.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/unity/)